# How to get JSON data from JIRA webhook

Tags: ruby, aws-lambda, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to setup a bot which will send a slack direct message when ticket from my jira board change their status to `'pending_informations'`.

I'm using AWS Lambda, according to the [docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/webhooks/) I've setup a Jira webhook to get ticket details from my Jira board. I've provided **URL** https://lambda_post_url where the callback should be sent. How to get to the JSON data that has been sent from Jira? I want to check how this JSON is defined and use this in further Slack implementation.

My lambda is pretty simple

```
module Bot
  module Handler
    extend self
    def handle(event:, context:)
      { statusCode: 200 }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How does the incoming request reach the provided code? The coded provided is a simple Ruby module and doesn't host a web-server by itself.

Comment: I don't have anything more than the code you see, should I set something more? I I thought I would get a JSON file by link with all defined data.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/ruby-handler.html), when look at the documentation they state the following: *"The event is a Ruby object that contains the payload that's provided by the invoker. If the payload is a JSON document, the event object is a Ruby hash. Otherwise, it's a string."*

Comment: Ok but I would like to see this json, what is inside of these hashes to get the right data - is this possible?

Comment: I've not worked with aws myself, but I guess you should take a look at [AWS Lambda Function Logging in Ruby](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/ruby-logging.html). Then simply output your `event` data using `p event` or `puts event.inspect`.

Answer (score 0):

I approached it in a different way, maybe someone will need something similar. So I just raised an error in my AWS Lambda for this event and check the AWS logs where I got rough JSON file which I could use locally.

Updated lambda to rise an error:

```
module Bot
  module Handler
    extend self
    def handle(event:, context:)
      raise StandardError.new(event)
      { statusCode: 200 }
    end
  end
end
```